# python chain of subprocess pipe dumps inconsistent result to file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have series of pipes where one pipe chains output to the next pipe's input. The first pipe takes data from a string variable. Each of them perform operation on the input. The last pipe is supposed to dump the result to a file. My problem is that the result dumped to the file is not consistent.

Here predstr is a large string, max_pred determines the number of subprocess to create.

```
def _bio2se(predstr, pred_base, prefix, max_pred):
    dump_file = '%s/prediction%s_preds' % (pred_base, prefix)
    _cmd = 'col-format.pl -%s -i bio -o se'
    start = sp.Popen((_cmd % ('1')).split(), stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)

    p = []
    p.append(start)
    for i in range(1, max_pred-1):
        p.append(sp.Popen((_cmd % str(i+1)).split(), stdin=p[i-1].stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE))

    if os.path.exists(dump_file):
        os.remove(dump_file)

    with open(dump_file, 'w') as dumpf: 
        sp.Popen((_cmd % str(max_pred)).split(), stdin=p[-1].stdout, stdout=dumpf)
        start.communicate(input=predstr.encode())
```

EDIT:
This works but it is not the intended solution as I dont want to write to file and read again.

```
def _bio2se_temp_file(predstr, pred_base, prefix, max_pred):
    dump_file = '%s/prediction%s_preds' % (pred_base, prefix)
    _cmd = 'col-format.pl -%s -i bio -o se'

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write(predstr.encode())
        f.seek(0)
        start = sp.Popen('cat'.split(), stdin=f, stdout=sp.PIPE)

    p = []
    p.append(start)
    for i in range(0, max_pred-1):
        p.append(sp.Popen((_cmd % str(i+1)).split(), stdin=p[i].stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE))

    if os.path.exists(dump_file):
        os.remove(dump_file)

    with open(dump_file, 'w') as dumpf: 
        end = sp.Popen((_cmd % str(max_pred)).split(), stdin=p[-1].stdout, stdout=dumpf)
```

Comment: What kind of inconsistency do you have? Maybe you need to .wait() for last subprocess termination inside "with ... as" block?

Comment: @VsevolodKulaga Iniitally the correct string are written to the file. Then some strings are not written (missing) and then again correct strings are written. I writed your wait suggestion. It did not work.